# How to design group chat like this

Tags: android, ios, swift, android-layout, user-interface

How to design group chat profile?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You only want the pictures to be 1 over another?
You can use RelativeLayout for that, it will put them over each other, you can then play with margin to move them as desired. You can also use toEndOf parameter and then give negative margin value to make them partly overlap.
Example

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/test_1"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image_1"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/test_2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/test_1"
            android:layout_marginStart="-20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image_2"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```